# .htaccess enabled, but not working

Tags: centos, .htaccess

I been having some very frustrating issues with getting .htaccess to work on my new server. I'm not very experienced in managing a server, but I've spent the last three days pouring over documentation and every resource I can get my hands on.

I've attempted to try a very basic application of .htaccess, and yet it fails to give the expected results. I've setup a test directory. Immediately within this directory is an .htaccess file with the following command:

> deny from all

If I'm not mistaken, this should deny access to /test, but it doesn't. It just sits there allowing anybody to view the contents. I've made a readable copy of the .htaccess available in the same directory for anybody wanting to see *exactly* what is going on in my .htaccess.

What could be wrong with my server/configuration? The server is running CentOS.

**Response to [Dom](https://serverfault.com/questions/146011/htaccess-enabled-but-not-working/146013#146013)**

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None
```

As suggested, I changed this to `AllowOverride All`, and then restarted my server:

```
service httpd restart
```

But received the following message:

> Syntax error on line 347 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
>   AllowOverride not allowed here [FAILED]

Line 347 is the last line below:

```
# UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
# directory if a ~user request is received.
#
# The path to the end user account 'public_html' directory must be
# accessible to the webserver userid.  This usually means that 
# ~useridllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in 
# .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `AllowOverride All` in your Virtualhost configuration ? if you have a `AllowOverride None`, the .htaccess file is not read, so it will not be used.
And right,

> deny from all

alone forbidden the connection to the folder.
And don't forget to reload apache

Comment: Would the `AllowOverride All` be in my httpd.conf file?

Comment: It depends of your platform. On my Debian/Ubuntu it is in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, but you can configure all your apache in httpd.conf.
Look for the "VirtualHost" parameter

Comment: @Dom I found a reference to `AllowOverride None` in my httpd.conf file. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Maybe if it is in the VirtualHost section. Could you put a copy of your httpd.conf in your server ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your edit. No it is not the right : this is for the root directory, not your virtualHost

Comment: @Dom I added a second edit. I'll see about placing a copy of my .conf in my web directory.

Comment: Check http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/linux/centos/apache_web_server/index.php, it explain Apache2 on CentOS. It is different from Debian a little

Comment: @Dom I'll check that resource out. I've added my httpd.conf file to my directory if you're able to scan it real quick.

Comment: Yes I check. The VirtualHosting is at the end but commented. Do you have some files in conf.d/ ? If you are your fils in /var/www/html, change the line 328 of your file

Comment: @Dom I'm sorry, I don't understand. Change line 328 to what?

Comment: Sorry : in your http.conf file, at line 328, change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All and reload apache

Comment: @Dom Alright. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Dom No success, unfortunately. I've updated the question with my present situation.

Comment: Do you have the original file ? Is there an error before this line ?

Comment: @Dom I can't even start Apache now... It's just giving me that error. Let me see if I can't fix it real quick.

Comment: Alright. I had to comment out line 347 to get the server to start again. I'm not sure what happened there.

Comment: And do you change the line 328 ? Is it works ?

Comment: @Dom I restored my `httpd.conf` from a backup, and restarted. I just now changed line 328 to `AllowOverride All`, restarted Apache, and IT WORKS! Thank you!